Startup USB and ISO disk for Ubuntu 24.04 won't work
I have used Ubuntu since version 18 and I was always able to get the ISO disk to offer a trial or installation as I upgraded to versions 20 and 22.  On April 25, 2024, I downloaded the 24.04 ISO file using a Windows 11 computer. It took about 4 hours.  The ISO for 24.04 is 5.7Gb and I copied it to an 8Gb DVD using the Ulead Burning program like in previous times. When I boot up and press F12 and select DVD for the boot option, I get a menu for try/install and check memory. Clicking on try/install, the program displays an underline on a black screen and nothing happens.  In previous versions, I could hear the DVD disk drive start spinning, but not for 24.04.
I also tried a USB thumb drive. I used rufus-4.4 to create the startup USB.  Again, just an underline displays, and nothing else happens.
I was thinking of waiting until the next update for 24.04 comes, but I would appreciate some suggestions if I am doing something wrong.
Thanks

If you have a fast internet, I suggest you download iso again from the official site and check your .iso https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview.

if you are already using a Ubuntu instance far better to use the Startup Disk Creator tool.

I am voting to close the question as OP decided to install Mint as the solution. Thus the problem can't be reproduced.

I had a similar issue with a USB installation stick.  What worked for me was to boot in "safe graphics" mode.

Safe Graphics mode does indeed work and proceeds to complete the installation. The normal way hangs or abruptly closes the installer. Restarting the installer in the normal mode does not complete at all.

I'd run into this type of problem with installing Ubuntu 24.04 myself.
Read this BUG report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/2059134
Especially the last 2 comments at the bottom.

I re-uploaded the ISO file for 24.04 using my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.  The download took only 8 minutes as compared to 4 hours the day before (probably because there was a lot of demand on the first day of release). I used Brasero to burn the ISO to DVD, and Startup Disk Creator to create a USB.
I tested the USB, and it works well.
On second thought, the problem that I reported may not have been a problem at all.  It is just a case of bad user interface and lack of feedback from the installation program. When the blinking cursor appears after selecting to try or install, I had to wait 13 minutes for anything to happen. All this time, there was just a blinking cursor on the screen. I would not have worried or reported the problem if the installation program had displayed: "loading data... please wait..."
Unfortunate conclusion: The Ubuntu 24.04 installation from DVD proceeded normally. I could hear the disk humming. I received the message to remove the media and press ENTER. I did so, and the rotating Ubuntu icon continued spinning on the screen. After waiting 10 minutes with no feedback, I turned off the laptop and rebooted. Ubuntu 24.04 came up.  When I clicked the Ubuntu software center icon, a white screen flashed and turned off. I could not establish normal operations without access to the software center.
I thought of going back to Ubuntu 22.04, but I decided to try Linux Mint instead.  What a difference! The installation of Linux Mint 21.3 had a progress bar that let me know what was happening.  The only glitch was at the end when I had to remove the media and press ENTER. There was no feedback, so I had to turn off the laptop and reboot. Linux Mint started normally and requested some updates that took about 15 minutes. I installed FreeFileSync, established communication with my Windows 11 PC, and restored my work files and folders. The transition from Ubuntu to Linux Mint was fairly easy.  I still have another laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.  I will wait to upgrade when 24.04-0.1 comes out in August. I hope to have a better experience.  If not, I will switch to Linux Mint.
