Bootable USB drive with Ubuntu 22.04/24.04 lts not passing from loading screen
I'm trying to do a dual-boot in my new PC gamer using Ubuntu 22.04/24.04 a few months, but I'm having some problems. After I update some drivers using Windows, my Pop'OS was crashing every time I boot it, so I uninstalled it.
So I tried to install Ubuntu 22.04/24.04 (lts) and they don't get past the loading phase when the Ubuntu logo appears. After that my usb reboots and then opens bootable USB options.
The USB drive is ok, as I already used it later to do other installations on my notebook.
I tried updating my BIOS and updating my drivers too, but it doesn't work for my issue.
I've installed Ubuntu before on this machine, so I don't think the problem is compatibility. I also ran memory tests and everything is normal.
My settings
CPU: Ryzen 7 5700x
GPU: RX 7600
Memory Cards: Asgard 32GB RAM
Motherboard: Gigabyte b550m aorus elite

This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511663/startup-usb-and-iso-disk-for-ubuntu-24-04-wont-work

Have you checked for any firmware updates for the B550? Those sometimes fix all sorts of problems.

Yes, I already updated.
I'll try this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/2059134

I was using Rufus to create a bootable partition in my pendrive, so I switch to balenaEtcher and WORKS!!!!

Thanks @amar! Your link was very helpful!

See this guide https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474717/create-usb-drive-contains-multi-ubuntu-versions-hbcd-pe-64-and-multi-windows-in

@ubfan1 You should add balena etcher as an answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-to-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-on-windows-mac-linux there is a mention of it but no how to.

I don't know, but...
For some reason, when I create a bootable USB using Rufus for Ubuntu 24.04 lts or Ubuntu 22.04 lts, ​​it doesn't boot after loading appears.
But when I use balenaEatcher it works.
Maybe I can try other bootable partition creators on USBs to test which ones work.

Sometimes when I start the installation process, the Ubuntu installation modals crash repeatedly too

Instead of Rufus, I used balenaEtcher to create the bootable partition on my USB drive.
And it worked!
Download: https://etcher.balena.io
